# Is there a way to change the color of the slds Checkbox Toggle?

Tags: lightning-design-system

I would like to change the color of the toggle to green from blue. I can't find a way in CSS to do it. Is there a way?

[image]

Comment: Is it in standard UI or the communities? I think you can do it using design tokens and override the colors.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/tokens_standard.htm

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is Standard UI

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was deep in the CSS.

.THIS .slds-checkbox_toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox_faux_container .slds- checkbox_faux{
           background-color:#218737!important;
}